# Facade Pattern in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns, facade

I tried to apply a facade pattern similar to the concept I did in Java, but I don't think it's exactly right. I think there is a problem in the `ShapeMaker` class or `Main`, do you think there is a problem here?

```
from __future__ import annotations

class Rectangle:
    def draw(self):
        print("Rectangle draw()")

class Square:
    def draw(self):
        print("Square draw()")

class Circle:
    def draw(self):
        print("Circle draw()")

class ShapeMaker:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.rectangle = Rectangle()
        self.square = Square()
        self.circle = Circle()

    def drawRectangle(self):
        self.rectangle.draw()

    def drawSquare(self):
        self.square.draw()

    def drawCircle(self):
        self.circle.draw()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    shapemaker = ShapeMaker()
    shapemaker.drawCircle()
    shapemaker.drawSquare()
    shapemaker.drawRectangle()
```

Comment: You have a typo in the `drawRectangle()`  method. It's calling the `circle` method.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen. Suppose that it is correct, is the concept a suitable concept?